# reading form a textfile not working

Tags: c++

I have a problem. When I run this code with the following text file :

```
car
3
4
-8 7
-+--
-7 1
```

and I try to print it, it prints up to number 7 and the last 2 characters are not being printed

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

```
    string srow;
    string scolumn;
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    string gametype;
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("text.txt");

    if (myReadFile.is_open())
    {
        getline(myReadFile, gametype);
        getline(myReadFile, srow);
        getline(myReadFile, scolumn);

        row = stoi(srow);
        column = stoi(scolumn);

        for (i = 0; i <row; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <column; j++)
            {
                myReadFile.get(ch);
                printf("%c",ch);
            }
        }
    }
    myReadFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed "4" to "5" in your text file , and it worked.

Comment: The number 4 represents the number of columns so by making it 5 it does not make sense. Also by making it 5 it printed one extra 1 at the end. thanks

Comment: nothing makes me sense here!

Comment: cool story bro needs more mcnuggets and big tasties

Answer (score 0):

If ch is a char...you are skipping the end of line. Your file really is:

```
car<\n>
3<\n>
4<\n>
-8 7<\n>
-+--<\n>
-7 1<\n>
```

<\n> is the end of line character, so.. if you read 4 chars x 2 lines (8 chars).. .you are reading:

```
12345678
-+--E-7
    ^
    |
     ----- End of line (</n)
```

You can use getline to avoid the end of line or read it in your for sentence, but be careful, Windows/DOS (\r\n) and Unix (\n) don't have the same [characters](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html) for end of line.

Answer (score 0):

It is giving wrong output because each line has `5` character not `4`. You are not considering `\n` at the end of the line. Last two characters are not getting printed because two `\n` are getting printed from above two lines. Changes to be done are:

```
Replace 
for (j = 0; j <column; j++)
with
for (j = 0; j <= column; j++)
```